# How to solve $a^{b^{c}} \pmod{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can I get step by step answer, because I want to fully understand this.

I tried solving:   $13^{51^{24}} \pmod{73}$

I used:
$a^{φ(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod m$ whenever $a$ is coprime to $m$.
$a^{(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, whenever $p$ is prime.

Now $\gcd(13,73) = 1$, $\gcd(51,73) = 1$ and  $13 \equiv 13 \pmod{73}$, so:

$((({13^{51} \pmod{73})}^{24}) \pmod{73}$

Set x = $13^{51} \pmod{73}$, so:
$x^{24} \equiv 13^{51^{24}}\pmod{73}$

$y^{72} ≡ 1\pmod{73}$
$(y^{24})^{3} ≡ 1\pmod{73}$

$[(y^{24})\pmod{73}*(y^{24})\pmod{73}*(y^{24})\pmod{73}] ≡ 1\pmod{73}$

I don't know how to continue.
Thanks.

Comment: You should type your questions using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) to make them more readable.  For example, `$13^{51^{24}} \pmod{73}$` will appear in a question, comment, or answer as $13^{15^{24}} \pmod{73}$.  Or, if you prefer, `$13\hat{}(51\hat{}(24)) \pmod{73}$` renders as $13\hat{}(51\hat{}(24)) \pmod{73}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!!Please consider using $\Latex$ for better formatting and better response to your question.Follow this link for a quick tutorial-http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is very hard to read.  As you point out, $13^{72}\equiv 1 \pmod {73}$,  Therefore you might be interested in computing $51^{24} \pmod {72}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A calculation variant:*

$\varphi(72)=\varphi(3^2)\varphi(2^3)=6\cdot 4=24$, so in the decomposition $51=3\cdot 17$, $17$, which is prime to $72$ has order a divisor of $24$. Hence
$$51^{24}\bmod72=3^24\bmod 72.$$
Now the powers of $3$ modulo $72$ are eventually cyclic:
$$\begin{array}{*{4}{c}}
k&2&3&4&5&6&\dots\\
3^k&9&27&9&27&9&\dots
\end{array}$$
Finally $51^{24}\equiv3^{24}\equiv 9\mod 72$.

Hence $13^{51^{24}}\equiv 13^9\mod 73$, which is easily calculated by the *fast exponentiation algorithm*:
$$\begin{array}{ccrcl}
n&&S&&P\\
\hline
9 &&13&&13\\
4&&169\equiv23&&13\\
2&&23^2\equiv 18&&13\\
1&&18^2\equiv32&&13\cdot 32\equiv \color{red}{51}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Why $51^{24} \pmod{72}$ ≡ $3^{2}4 \pmod{72}$ ?
Because gcd(51,72) = 3 $\neq$ 1 so I can't use euler's theorem.
So:
$(17\cdot3)^{24} \pmod{72}$ ≡ $3^{24} \cdot17^{24} \pmod{72}$ ≡ $[3^{24} \pmod{72}\cdot17^{24} \pmod{72}] \pmod{72}$
gcd(17,72) = 1,so:
$17^{24} ≡1 \pmod{72}$
then:
$[3^{24} \pmod{72}\cdot1] \pmod{72}$
and then:
 $5^{24} ≡ 3^{24} \pmod{72}$

Is there another way(without use of calculator) to calculate $3^{24} \pmod{72}$ ?
Thanks.

Comment: I've shown that, if $k\ge 2$, $3^k\equiv 9$ if $k is even, $27$ if $k$ is odd. What do you want a calculator?

Comment: Is there another way to calculate (without using fast modular exponentiation):
$$\mbox{ }$$
$13^{9}\pmod{73}$
?
$$\mbox{ }$$
Is there another way to calculate (without using fast modular exponentiation or check if it cyclic):
$$\mbox{ }$$
$3^{24}\pmod{72}$
?
$$\mbox{ }$$
Thanks.

Comment: Except using a computer algebra system that will do it for you, I don't see.